# typescript history js conflict

Tags: typescript

I am using history.js declaration file from the link below.

[History.js declaration file](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/history/history-1.7.d.ts)

However, the "History" object is conflicting with native History object in lib.d.ts. Is there a way to overcome this issue? I triple checked, I am including the reference to the history.js declaration file.

Comment: Github files have moved yet again: now at https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/history

Answer (score 3):

I have sent a pull request to the Definitely Typed project to change the definition file to this:

```
interface HistoryAdapter {
    bind(element, event, callback);
    trigger(element, event);
    onDomLoad(callback);
}

interface History {
    enabled: bool;
    pushState(data, title, url);
    replaceState(data, title, url);
    getState();
    getHash();
    Adapter: HistoryAdapter;
    back();
    forward();
    go(X);
    log(...messages: any[]);
    debug(...messages: any[]);
}
```

This gracefully adds the additional properties and methods to the existing interface and so on to the existing History class definition, so using:

```
var history = new History();
```

Should now work. Just [grab the latest History definition from Definitely Typed](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/history/history-1.7.d.ts).

### Edit:

Github links have changed (yet again). File is now at: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/history

Comment: Thanks so much. This would work from the generated javascript perspective. However, I was getting an error in the declaration file saying "Duplicate identifier Adapter" and "Duplicate identifier enabled". I removed those 2 properties and the errors went away, so you could update the DefinitelyTyped project.

Comment: When I removed those 2 properties and there is an error in my .ts file saying "there is no Adapter property in History".

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just cast your object to the `HistoryStatic` interface provided by DefinitelyTyped.

```
var h = new History();
h = <HistoryStatic>h;
h.getState();
```

It would be better if the declaration file extended the already provided `History` interface of `lib.d.ts` instead of creating its own interface. Perhaps there was an intention for this or maybe it was overlooked.