# Typescript: History and File are already defined

Tags: typescript

I wrote a new application using Typescript, and I wrote new classes named 'File' and 'History'. However, I found out that these names collide with internal names of Typescript. Do you know how to avoid this collision?

I also watched this link and unfortunately the links there are dead: [typescript history js conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149936/typescript-history-js-conflict)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you export your classes then you shouldn't have a problem:

file1.ts

```
export class File { ... }

export class History { ... }
```

file2.ts

```
import { File as MyFile, History as MyFistory } from "./file1";

let file = new MyFile();
```

or

```
import * as MyModule from "./file1";

let file = new MyModule.File();
```

If you don't use modules then you'll need to rename your classes to avoid this collision.